Issue with Combining Scheduled Pipelines and Setup Workflow in the Same Configuration
I’m encountering an issue with combining a setup workflow and a scheduled pipeline within the same configuration file. My goal is to use the setup workflow to dynamically configure modules and then run a scheduled pipeline. However, when I attempt to do this, I receive the following error: Max number of workflows exceeded.
Here is a simplified version of my configuration file:
version: 2.1

setup: << pipeline.parameters.run-setup >>

parameters:
  run-setup:
    description: Whether it is a setup workflow or a continuation
    type: boolean
    default: true
  force-all:
    description: Emergency valve
    type: boolean
    default: false

workflows:
  setup-workflow:
    when: << pipeline.parameters.run-setup >>
    jobs:
      - config-splitting/setup-dynamic-config:
          force-all: << pipeline.parameters.force-all >>
          base-revision: main
          modules: |
            digital-scheduling-solution/dss-submit

  check_scan:
    when:   
      and:
        - equal: [ scheduled_pipeline, << pipeline.trigger_source >> ]
        - equal: [ "Check Scan", << pipeline.schedule.name >> ]
    jobs:
      - config-splitting/scan_services:
          context: services

